# How to do a column name inside of a dynamic where clause? TO_NUMBER(column name)

Tags: oracle11g

I am currently trying to create a dynamic Select statement when the user has to input a various amount of criteria to search by.

Currently, I have every part of the statement working except for the most important part.

I am attempting to do something like this:

```
selStmt := 'SELECT column_one, column_2, column_3
            FROM nerf
whereClause := ' WHERE TO_NUMBER('''|| column_one ||''') <= '''|| userInput ||'''';
```

However, in doing this the WHERE cluse of my SELECT statement is not accurate as shown by my output line:

```
WHERE TO_NUMBER('') <= '5';
```

I have tried various solutions with quote marks and I end up with either a ORA-00905 missing identifier error, or I get a ORA-00911: invalid character error.

At this point I'm not quite sure how to approach this issue.

Any useful help gets thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason, Oracle uses the single quote to delimit strings and to escape characters, so using `''` is an instruction to Oracle to add a quote inside your string. Example:

```
'This is a string with a quote here: '' and then it ends normally'
```

will be represented as

```
This is a string with a quote here: ' and then it ends normally
```

In your example, you are ending the `WHERE` clause you're building up and then concatenating a PL/SQL variable identifier called `column_one`:

```
' WHERE TO_NUMBER('''|| column_one ||''')
```

...and with a `NULL` value for the identifier `column_one` this is represented as

```
 WHERE TO_NUMBER('')
```

Presumably you want to reference `column_one` from inside the query, and not from a PL/SQL variable of the same name, so you should remove the quotes around it like so:

```
whereClause := ' WHERE TO_NUMBER(column_one) <= TO_NUMBER('''|| userInput ||''')';
```

Escaping strings in Oracle is often infuriating - it helps a lot if you have a good IDE with decent syntax highlighting like TOAD or SQL*Developer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, Oracle developer is okay if you don't have stuff in quotes already, but I'm pretty new to it and I'm still getting used to it.

I also really liked that you explained it a little instead of just giving the answer.

I would vote you up, but I lack the rep for voting currently, new user.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
selStmt := 'SELECT column_one, column_2, column_3 FROM nerf';
whereClause := ' WHERE TO_NUMBER(column_one) <= TO_NUMBER('''|| userInput ||''')';
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'm a little more irritated that it was something so easily missed, but I'll get over it.

I would vote you up, but I don't have the rep to vote yet. New user.